# Scaffold DisplayFor instead of EditorFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an asp.net MVC 5 site.

When I scaffold a view it always generates EditorFor on each property.

What data annotation can I use to get it to generate DisplayFor on some fields (as they only need to be displayed not edited)?

Weirdly I can find nothing on Google about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a little trick using the [`UIHintAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

First, create a new **EditorTemplate** in your `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates` folder, with the name `DisplayOnly.cshtml`, the only content is the line

```
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Then, mark your Attributes which are never edited but displayed, with the `UIHintAttribute`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [UIHint("DisplayOnly")]
    public string OnylyDisplayed { get; set; }

    public string Editable { get; set; }
}
```

Even if `EditoFor(...)` is scaffolded, the Template engine will route you to the Display Template.

**EDIT**

I was sure this would work this way, but I had issued getting it working the first time; interestingly, something like `@Html.LabelForModel()` in the Template works. Maybe I'm missing something. What will work is, if you need a simple output, to just have `@Model` in the template. You could use multiple different Editor Templates which act as read only, for different types.

Comment: thanks - so it would make sense for them to add this capability to DataAnnotations